# Code running in background while at breakpoint in Android Studio

Tags: android, multithreading, debugging, opengl, breakpoints

As I step through my code using F8, after setting a breakpoint, I don't understand how there is code running while the code should be stopped. It is an Android 3D game, and even though the code is stopped, there is a graphics object rotating in the background as if it is in a separate thread from the code that I am debugging or something.

The game code is huge, and there isn't really any point in showing any code, but if there are any specific questions about the code I can either answer it or show some snippet.

Very strange. Any ideas anyone?

[EDIT] I am using Java and Opengl ES 2.0. No third party software.

The code has one thread that I created to handle audio record data.

The main activity has an onTouchEvent() background thread which gets called when an touch event occurs, but that code only processes input data as it occurs, and I don't touch the screen during this particular debug.

The activity also of course has the opengl onDrawFrame() thread which runs all game logic.  I suppose there is a good chance this is where the problem lies.

With Opengl ES apps should game logic be run in a separate thread from the render loop? I think thread would be huge, and there would be a similar problem... graphics code executing in a thread while trying to single step through code in the debugger.

Maybe there is a way for threads to be force stopped when running in Android Studio?

[/EDIT]

Comment: I think you gave the answer on your own. Most likely the animation process is being done on a different thread and since you are debugging a single thread, the other ones are running normally

Comment: @Dan Baruch The only multi-threaded code in the entire project is a thread with only a few lines for processing audio-record data in the background. No graphics or game logic exists in that thread.

Comment: I must say I find what you say rather weird. Almost any game, especially 3D ones use multiple threads for a lot of processing. Are you sure that there are no threads involved? Are you perhaps using a 3rd party library which uses threads?

Comment: @Dan Baruch Thanks. I edited the OP with a little more explanation.